# How to .prettify single line into multiple lines?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The code snippet that comes out of this is one single long line. **How can I make it so it's multiple lines** as it appears in the url? I think I need `.prettify` but couldn't figure out how to use it in this context. If .prettify is not the solution, then of course I'm open to suggestions.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

test = urllib.request.urlopen('https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/143165/FASM-1.7.21-Buffer-Overflow.html').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(test, 'lxml')

output = soup.find('pre')
print(output.code.text)
```

Comment: post the exact expected result

Comment: this is everything. im just trying to print whats in the `code` tags but without losing the format. it comes out as a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`strings` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) you can iterates lines (separated by `<br>`). Join them by newline (`\n`) will give you what you want:

```
print('\n'.join(output.code.strings))
```

---

or iterate lines and print them:

```
for line in output.code.strings:
    print(line)
```

---

or replace `<br>`s with newlines:

```
for br in output.code.find_all('br'):
    br.replace_with('\n')
print(output.code)
```